# Запись синтеза речи TTS

Tags: python, tts

Требуется помощь в реализации записи синтеза речи TTS и сохранении её в виде аудиофайла.

Пытался найти реализацию в Google, нашёл пару, но те были не рабочие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример реализации, [подробнее](https://googleapis.dev/python/texttospeech/latest/index.html)

```
from google.cloud import texttospeech

client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code="ru-RU", name="ru-RU-Wavenet-A"
)
audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
synthesis_input = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text="Привет, мир!")

response = client.synthesize_speech(
    input=synthesis_input, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config

with open("output.wav", "wb") as out:
    out.write(response.audio_content)
```

Comment: Хотелось бы использовать более лёгкую Lib. Если есть возможность было бы круто чтобы Вы показали её пример.

Comment: @m0Lb ну есть ещё pyttsx3, лёгкая, бесплатная)

Comment: Как организовать запись синтеза через pyttsx3?

Comment: @m0Lb https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/